# Facebook Authentication before showing page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, facebook-authentication

I trying to use facebook authentication in my ember.js app. If the use already have session with facebook (he already have opened facebook in another tab) and he visits my page, first login screen is shown for a moment and as soon as application gets response from facebook, user is redirected to Welcome page.

If user already have facebook session, How can I wait for facebook response and based on response decide to show my html.

In other words, I want to execute my javascript code before rendering the page. I am using following library for facebook authentication 
http://luansantos.com/2012/03/06/using-facebook-js-sdk-with-emberjs/

Answer (score 0):

Use [deferReadiness](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_deferReadiness) method
for ember-facebook it could look like this (not tested):

```
App = Em.Application.create(Em.Facebook);
App.deferReadiness();
App.set('appId', 'YourAppId');

App.addObserver("/auth-token",  function(sender, key, value) {
  if(value == false) {
     App.advanceReadiness();
  }
});
```